# SoundCloud Widget API and rate limits

Tags: soundcloud

I'm just about to start creating a custom SoundCloud integration for a client, but am a bit confused as to the application of the API call limit. Does this limit affect the html5 widget or the html5 widget API? To my understanding, it is loading the content (in this case, a playlist) through an iFrame and not through an outright custom player, and the widget API exposes the widget's controls and info to the global scope.

I do apologise if this has been asked before - I did try searching SoundCloud posts but could not find this answer.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud widget player is not affected by rate limit according to the SoundCloud developers announcement.

Visit here. https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/limits

You can find following description.
"These limits are applied to developer applications using the SoundCloud API, and have no impact on the SoundCloud embedded player."